# Connection problem with local db Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, connection-string

I am creating my first local db with Visual Studio.

I created one project where I installed entity framework, "ConsoleApp4". Then I created a seperate lib "ClassLibrary" (dll) where I added a database (mdf).

I have also built a connection string in numerous ways and put in "ConsoleApp4" app.config.

I am using package manager console to add-migrations and then update database.

The db is created however it is a new db (created a by entity framework) and not the db in the "classLibrary".

How do I get entity framework to understand that it should connect to the db I created in the class library (and just add the new tables)?

Comment: One more thing I tried test connection under modify connection (right click on db) and it works....

Comment: Looked at services but didnt find nay sql server service.....is this maybe the error or maybe it doesnt matter on a local db?

Comment: Saw another thing beofre I run the command in PM console the state of the db is open but then when i run update-databse it changes to closed??

Comment: SQL express is also installled. Damn it whats wrong!? :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm working a project with .net and my connection string looks like this, maybe it can help you

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=yourdatasource;Initial Catalog=yourcatalogname;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>`
```

Comment: Tried it..seemed to work i.e test connection worked but I still get the error 26...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by assign the name of the connection string i the db context constructor.

Now it works!